# How to add condition ORDER BY in Confluence CQL?

Tags: confluence

We are trying to sort this CQL by the created parameter as per below CQL.

type=page and created >= startOfMonth("-90d")

Referred to the [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/advanced-searching-using-cql/#order-by), but got the error when compiling

```
Could not parse cql
```

CQLs that had been tried

```
type=page AND created >= startOfMonth("-90d") AND order by created

type=page AND created >= startOfMonth("-90d") asc 

type=page order by created AND created >= startOfMonth("-90d")

(type=page order by created) AND (created >= startOfMonth("-90d")).
```

Any pointers we missed or we should look at?

Appreciate your response in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` should be the last part of your JQL/CQL and does not require the inclusion of `AND`.

This CQL is untested, however I believe it should work: `type=page AND created >= startOfMonth("-90d") ORDER BY created`

See docs here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/advanced-searching-using-cql/#order-by